# Show a bar as indicator of time spent on a task

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have been assigned with the task of designing a screen used for time management as C# Windows application. I need to show time spent on a task in a graphical bar like pattern. I have added the desired output image for your reference.
[image]

The bar will be controlled by start/stop buttons and once I start, the bar will keep on increasing in size with every tick of the timer control.
Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to start.

Comment: Mr. Downvoter, would you mind adding a comment to help me improve please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using grant chart for this type of requirement.

http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#gantt-charts

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, you were really fast! :) Is there any other tool that can be used here?